# Heap Sort Algorithm number of comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of comparisons in this heap sort algorithm:

```
import random
import time

#HeapSort Algorithm
def heapify(arr, n, i):
    count = 0
    largest = i  
    l = 2 * i + 1     
    r = 2 * i + 2     
    if l < n and arr[i] < arr[l]:
        largest = l
    if r < n and arr[largest] < arr[r]:
        largest = r
    if largest != i:
        count += 1
        arr[i],arr[largest] = arr[largest],arr[i]
        heapify(arr, n, largest)
    return count

def heapSort(arr):

    n = len(arr)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, n, i)  
        count += heapify(arr, i, 0)
    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        arr[i], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[i] 
        heapify(arr, i, 0)

    return count

print("For n = 1000:")

print("a) Random Generation:")

arr = [x for x in range(1000)]
random.shuffle(arr)

print("Before Sort:")
print (arr)

print("After Sort:")
start_time = time.time()
heapSort(arr)
time = time.time() - start_time
print(arr)

print("Comparisions")
print(heapSort(arr))
print("Time:")
print(time)
```

I expect the result when n = 1000 integers to be 8421 and when n = 10000 to be 117681

However, each time it either shows 0 or 2001 when I try to count += 1 around the loops and not comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be forgetting to take into account the comparisons your recursive solution makes while solving the smaller subproblems. In other words, you are only finding the comparisons made in the topmost level of your solution. Instead, you should update the `count` variable in the relevant scope whenever you make a call to your `heapify` function. Notice the updates below where I increased local `count` variables by the return value of calls to heapify.

```
def heapify(arr, n, i):
    count = 0
    largest = i  
    l = 2 * i + 1     
    r = 2 * i + 2     
    if l < n and arr[i] < arr[l]:
        largest = l
    if r < n and arr[largest] < arr[r]:
        largest = r
    if largest != i:
        count += 1
        arr[i],arr[largest] = arr[largest],arr[i]
        count += heapify(arr, n, largest)
    return count

def heapSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, n, i)  
        count += heapify(arr, i, 0)
    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        arr[i], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[i] 
        count += heapify(arr, i, 0)
    return count
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/Te5Wul) is a working example of your code including the fix given above. I understand that the output is still slightly different than the exact number of comparisons you are expecting, but it is in the ballpark. The relatively small distance is due to the fact that you are randomizing the initial state of the array.

Comment: Ahh right, I didn't consider the count due to the recursion! Thanks ilim!

Answer (score 0):

The Heap sort takes on the basis of heap time complexity which amy lead upto O(nlogn) + Time taken to setup the Heap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).